# Is Google Analytics Business Intelligence Tool

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, business-intelligence

I tried to search if Google Analytics is in the category of Business Intelligence Tools, My personal opinion Yes, but i am not able to find a convincing answer on net. I would appreciate if someone with experience in BI tools can tell me if Google Analytics really falls  under the category of BI Tools. I use Google Analytics almost everyday and design our marketing strategy according with marketing team.

So can i say i have worked on BI tools towards achieving Business goals. (Please dont mark this question as negative as it may sound stupid but StackOverFlow is the best place to get replies from experts)

Comment: Look Google Analytics application galleries categories and tell me what you find out. However, Web is no always all the business and marketing is not the only area that could use bi.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: https://www.google.com/analytics/data-studio/ this is a google BI tool compete against Microsoft power BI and Tableau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google Analytics is not a business intelligence tool.

There are lots of competing definitions out there, but here is a reasonably good explanation of why not:

> The goals of web analytics are slightly different from traditional
>   business intelligence objectives: web analytics aims to measure user
>   interactions from online marketing awareness, social media, mobile,
>   video interactions, and of course, the web itself. Those are
>   non-personally identifiable activities, largely non-transactional (in
>   classic IT terminology), they have a relatively short lifespan and are
>   much closer to the realm of statistics - with implications of sampling
>   and margin of error. On the other end, business intelligence relies
>   heavily on historical transactional data where integrity is
>   reinforced, customers are identified and the timespan require longer,
>   more thorough analysis which will lead to improved business process
>   and better strategies.

- http://blog.immeria.net/2010/04/web-analytics-it-and-business.html

You can make a strong case for web analytics as a critical function of business, and you should relate your use of GA in terms of business objectives, but it won't meet a strict definition of BI.

---

As an aside, if this is for a job application, people would rather hear the direct results of your work with GA, rather than saying you "have worked on BI tools towards achieving Business goals".

For example: I reduced bounce rates by 30%, resulting in an increase of sales of blue widgets by $1 million.